# how to get back the loader after Event.COMPLETE with my code? (as3, flash)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, event-handling, loader

can you please tell me how you get the loader back after a Event.COMPLETE?

i tried the example from the doc, i tried different stuff, but i always have a "error to convert Loader in LoaderInfo, or in myImport..."

this does not work : `TypeError: Error #1034:`

```
function loader_my_import(){
    var loader = new Loader();
    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("myImport.swf");
    loader.load(url);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete_imgs);
}

function complete_imgs(e:Event){
      loader_IMGS = Loader(e.target.content);
}
```

loader_IMGS being already declared at the beginning of the class.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because e.target is a [LoaderInfo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) object not a loader (you add the event listener to the [contentLoaderInfo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#contentLoaderInfo) ). From the LoaderInfo you can then get the originate [loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#loader)

So it should be :

```
function complete_imgs(e:Event){
 var li:LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(e.target)
 var loader:Loader = li.loader
}
```

Comment: thanks Patrick! Can you please tell me something : what will the preload of my `mainClass.swf` preload? i have several loaders that are loading at the beginning of my class, just after `added_to_stage`, the preloader reads through all the code and preload also those loaders? because i also preload other loaders that come on screen with some tweenlite, and that are then removed from stage, i need them to be loaded and be sure they are, before the user starts to use the website... thanks

Comment: @Paul sorry didn't understand ?

Comment: i meant, i load my main class into a "preloading" class : preload.as will load main.as, but i'm wondering what it actually load inside "main.as"? in main.as, i have several methods : "added_to_stage", then other methods are called like "load_all_my_loaders", etc. so the "preload" loads main.as, this means only the fla? or will it load also all the loaders from the method "load_all_my_loaders", is that more clear? thanks anyway for the answer above